# Where can I get memcached for Windows 64Bit

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, memcached

I have checked other answers on SO but they are all old. I just cannot find a place to get memcached for windows 64bit. Where can I find it. Also, where do I find the windows clients for memcached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32 bit should run on windows 64 machines. Regardless, check [Membase server](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/memcached), it has memcached bundeled, it can be run in memcached only mode (i.e. no persistence).

Below links should also be of interest:

[Memcache on windows](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/PlatformWindows)

http://allegiance.chi-town.com/MemCacheDManager.aspx

And this SO question: [can I get Memcached running on a Windows (x64) 64bit environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896/memcached-on-windows-x64)

Answer (score 3):

If this can help someone, I've done a wrapper based on a compilation of memcached 1.4.5 64-bits found through [this page](http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/08/25/Memcached-1.4.5-for-Windows) ([direct link to NorthScale binary](http://downloads.northscale.com/memcached-1.4.5-amd64.zip)).

It's a windows service:
https://github.com/eric-b/MemcachedService64

Client side, I use the [Enyim caching](https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached) (*Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient*)

Answer (score 2):

The latest windows installers for memcached are found at below mentioned link:

[Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=37578)

It contains the 64 bit version for Windows. I am not sure whether it is authentic or not. Even I foind while searching on google. Need to make sure it is right site.

Hope this will help someone.