# Where to get updated MemCached for Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, memcached

Does somebody know Where to get compiled and updated MemCached executable for Windows?

And also the .Net Framework memcached client?

(The latest stable memcached release is v1.4.10)

Comment: I think you can find it here http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/

Comment: You want to know where to download the .NET Framework?

Comment: @Ramhound no, he's after the memcached server software and bindings (client) to talk to it

Comment: Maybe a bit duplicate aswell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896/memcached-on-windows-x64

Answer (score 1):

Yes here:

[Membase Server](http://www.couchbase.com/downloads/membase-server/community)

But you'll have to deploy it in "Memcached Mode" see here:

[Looking for memcached page](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/memcached)

And [this](http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/) is the client I use it's a bit old (from 2010) but it works reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

I just started messing w/ MemCached for windows today, I am currently using the [Enyim client](https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached). I beleive it is in active development and the latest build is from Oct. It is very simple to use and does the basics. [Here](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/memcached-for-c----a-walkthrough/62) is an article that explains what was needed to get it all up and running.

Comment: That client does look promissing. Also cool that is works with membase.