# How to install Memcached on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, memcached

I was trying to install Memcached using "-d install", wasn't working with an error. However, it was recommended to use NSSM to install the service. I read somewhere that running memcahced as a service would stick to only 64 MB regardless of the command line options you give it.

What's the right way to install Memcached on a windows server with a different "-m" option not the default?

Thanks

Comment: What build of MemCached are you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9806441/120398 for various builds...