# Install php memcache on Windows Server 2008 x64

Tags: php, windows, memcached, 64-bit, xampp

I'm running XAMPP 1.8.1 on Win Server 2008 R2 x64, and my PHP version is 5.4.7.

I've followed [this](http://www.leonardaustin.com/technical/how-to-install-memcached-on-xampp-on-windows-7) with the installation, downloaded php_memcache-3.0.7-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip from [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.7/) and also replaced the memcached service file from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896/memcached-on-windows-x64/9806441#9806441).

The service is upped and the extension in php.ini is also added, but I still can't see the mod is enabled in phpinfo().

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that memchaced service is running

`telnet 127.0.0.1 11222` (install a telnet client If you don't have)

If it fails that means your memchaced build is not running.

---

For windows consider to move to [couchbase with memchaced bucket](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-architecture-buckets.html). IMHO, That's the known best implementation.

Comment: So with Couchbase, I think this might be a better link - http://www.couchbase.com/memcached

Also a post to a related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896/memcached-on-windows-x64/9806441#9806441