# Can Couchbase Server work with RAM memory only?

Tags: nosql, memcached, couchbase

We want to take advantage of the No-Sql Databases in our applications, and we found out about Couchbase.

I've read about it on another [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896/memcached-on-windows-x64), where somebody says that you can configure Couchbase to work with Memcached only (so it saves data only on memory, not on disks also).

However, i haven't found anything about this in the [documentation](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-getting-started-setup.html).

Is it possible to setup Couchbase server to work with RAM memory?

Or, you specify on the client side where the data should be saved? (disk or memory)

Comment: Under what scenario would this apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Just use [memcached buckets](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/concept-dataStorage.html). That's all

Comment: That link is broken, but one can learn about [memcached buckets here](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/concept-dataStorage.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check out: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-introduction-basics.html

Couchbase 2.0 documentation explicitly states that it's an in-memory database. From my experience the buckets all exist in RAM. You can set the size of every bucket to partition your RAM appropriately.

Comment: it is not completely an in memory database, you can have more data than RAM. Couchbase caches as much data as possible but data are persisted. As mention in the previous commnent you can use a Memcache bucket, but most of the user simply use Couchbase Bucket is a proper RAM size and in this case everything is in memory (and on the disk, quite important in case of failure)