# memcached on windows x64 - update?

Tags: windows, memcached, 64-bit, couchbase

I'm looking for memcached to run on Windows x64. I saw a old thread [can I get Memcached running on a Windows (x64) 64bit environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896/memcached-on-windows-x64) and looked at Couchbase site. Looks like they have taken a different direction on their product. I didn't see any download/support for windows x64 memcached from them. Appreciate if someone share latest information about memcached to run on windows x64.

Comment: Have you tried just google "memcached windows" and follow 3 basic steps that from all search results: 1)download and unzip binaries; 2) install memcached as a service; 3)run service?