# how to connect to cachedb (intersystems) from php (on windows) natively?

Tags: php, database, caching, intersystems-cache

I am hoping it is possible to connect to a CacheDB from PHP, without using ODBC.   I have found the ODBC connectivity to Cache is not reliable a number of times, so I am hoping there is some other native method / driver I can use to connect to a Cache DB?

If it's not possible through PHP, I might consider .net (VB or C#) if it's possible there.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use memcached, read this [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896/memcached-on-windows-x64

Comment: To connect to Intersystems Cache DB?

Comment: my bad, add  intersystems to your title

Comment: I would consider languages other than the above also...